# Function that gives -1 and +1 with change in x.

Tags: functions

I need a function $f(x)$ that gives either $-1$ or $1$ based on $x$.

eg.

- when $x = 26$ it should give me $1$,
- when $x = 27$ it should give me $-1$,
- when $x = 28$ it should give me $1$,

and so on.

I know it had something to do with modulas(reminders of division), but i  can't get it.

Comment: Is $x$ real or an integer?

Comment: x is real and i would be happy if it could change values quickly.

Comment: Does it need to be continuous like $\cos(\pi x)$ or can it be disontinuous like $(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ ?

Comment: @jaapScherphuis it should be continuous. values changing every 'k' change in x. ie z -> -1 , z+k -> 1, z+2k -> -1 and so on..

Comment: I don't think you know what [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) means, since the answer you just accepted is a discontinuous function.

Comment: sorry, im a medical student far from math. yeah i want discontinuous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one ([plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%201-%202floor%28x%29%2B4floor%20%28x%2F2%29%20for%20x%3D1..10))

$$f(x) = 1-2\lfloor x \rfloor+4\lfloor x/2 \rfloor$$

[image]